# Set the server farm (aka web hosting plan) when running New-AzureWebsite

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am using Azure Powershell to create a new Azure Website:

```
New-AzureWebsite -Name MyWebsiteName
```

Azure creates it in the `Default1` server farm, whereas I need it in `DefaultServerFarm`.

Using the `-location` parameter doesn't work to specify the server farm, because the `Default1` and `DefaultServerFarm` plans are both in `"West US"`, and the location parameter does not take a server farm name as its value.

Using `-slot` doesn't work either, thought I am not sure what is supposed to go in that parameter, it throws an `EndpointNotFoundException` if I try to run it with `DefaultServerFarm` as its value.

How can we create a new azure website with Powershell and set its server farm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot assign a web hosting plan when running the traditional `New-AzureWebSite`.

To have this power and control, you have to use the [newest version of Azure PowerShell](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/) and switch to [AzureResourceManager mode](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/#create).

Here is some tested PowerShell code:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription "Your Subscription Name"
New-AzureResource -Name NewWebSite `
    -Location "West Europe" `
    -ResourceGroupName 'Default-Web-WestEurope' `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' `
    -ApiVersion '2014-04-01-preview' `
    -PropertyObject @{ 'ServerFarm' = 'DefaultServerFarm' }
```

Note, if your account is associated with multiple subscription you have to explicitly select the subscription under which the targeted Resource Group and Server Farm are. If you only have one subscription you can skip this line (`Select-AzureSubscription`)

Comment: How does one find out what `PropertyObject` values are appropriate?